# Kivy adding widget arguments error

Tags: python, csv, widget, kivy

When I try to add a Label with the variable 'arrowscore' retrieved from a .csv file I encounter the error:

```
TypeError: add_widget() missing 1 required positional argument: 'widget'
```

This is my base code:

```
class EvaluateScreen(Screen):
pass


class EvaluateLayout(BoxLayout):
    global endNo
    def update(stuff):
        def readMe(endNo, i):
            f = open("end" + str(endNo) + ".csv", "r")  # opens the csv
            lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f] #reads the lines of the file
            del lines[0] #removes the meta-value inside of the file
            lines = lines[0] #extracts a 1d array (single line) from the lines
            lines = lines.split(",") #splits the csv line into separate values in a list
            print(lines) #for debugging purposes
            f.close()  # closes the file
            return lines[int(i)] # returns the requested value

        if canDrawScores == True: #if an external variable is true
            for i in range(0,5): #for values 0 to 5
                arrowScore = readMe(endNo, i)
                BoxLayout.add_widget(Label(text=str(arrowScore))) #add a new label to the BoxLayout with text as the retrieved value

    Clock.schedule_interval(update, 0.5) #checking if the external variable is true every half second
```

--- EDITED BUT STILL BROKEN ----
Now the code is raising an AttributeError in self.do_layout, stating that 'float' object has no attribute 'do_layout'
    class EvaluateScreen(Screen):
        pass

```
class EvaluateLayout(BoxLayout):
    global endNo
    global endLimit
    def update(self):
        self.do_layout()
        def readMe(endNo, i):
             f = open("end" + str(endNo) + ".csv", "r")  # opens the end
            lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f] #reads the lines of the file
            del lines[0]
            lines = lines[0]
            lines = lines.split(",")
            print(lines)
            f.close()  # closes the file
            return lines[int(i)] # returns the requested value

        if canDrawScores == True:
            for i in range(0,endLimit):
               arrowScore = readMe(endNo, i)
               self.add_widget(Label(text=str(arrowScore)))

Clock.schedule_interval(update, 0.5)


evaluatescreen = EvaluateScreen()
evaluatelayout = EvaluateLayout()
evaluatescreen.add_widget(evaluatelayout)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using BoxLayout(the type) instead of self(an instance of BoxLayout)

```
 def update(stuff):

     BoxLayout.add_widget(Label(text=str(arrowScore))) #add a new label to the BoxLayout with text as the retrieved value
```

Change to...

```
 def update(self, dt): #<---changed stuff to self and added dt (delta_time)

     self.add_widget(Label(text=str(arrowScore))) #add a new label to the BoxLayout with text as the retrieved value
```

Now the last problem:

```
Clock.schedule_interval(update, 0.5) #checking if the external variable is true every half second
```

This is done on the EvaluateLayout.update method and not on an EvaluateLayout instance.update ... You need somthing alone these lines

```
el = EvaluateLayout()#creating the layout here...
#and later on...
Clock.schedule_interval(el.update, 0.5) #checking if the external variable is
```

Comment: I've got the error: "NameError: name 'self' is not defined" even though it should be instantiated on startup.

Comment: @EtherealHawk - I've updated the answer to fix another problem with the update definition. you named self as stuff by mistake

Comment: It's so strange I'm updating my base code, I've renamed it and such and now it's raising another error on the line self.do_layout() - AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'do_layout'